# Better Workflow equivalent for EE 3.x

Tags: ee3, better-workflow

Better Workflow will not be updated for EE 3.x - described here - http://betterworkflow.electricputty.co.uk/news/ee3-support/

I'd like to be able to save a channel entry in 'draft' format. An Admin should be able to preview the draft but members of the public should not.

Is there an EE 3.x compatible plugin that does this, or a method by which I can code it in?

As a side note I'm finding quite a lot of things which EE 3.x seems to lack, which seems like very standard functionality in every other CMS, this being a good example. It's also very frustrating that plugins that worked in EE 2.x are being abandoned and no equivalents or further developments are being done, although I understand 2.x and 3.x are very different. Has anyone else got any thoughts on this? It's to the extent that 2.x actually seems better than 3.x in terms of features, which does not seem right unless I'm missing something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using custom statuses? I typically have a 'draft' status, which ties in with an environment variable, which in turn allows you to filter all your channel entries tags to only show draft or open entries depending on which environment is being viewed. You can then instruct your editors to create new entries in draft status, preview them on the testing environment and then switch them to open status to launch live.

It's admittedly a much more simplistic workflow than Better Workflow provides, but it covers the most common client need for me. The only thing this technique doesn't allow for is previewing changes to entries that are already live. In those cases I usually recommend that an editor clones the entry they want to test. Once cloned, they can make changes to that clone in draft status, test/get approval on the test site and then set the entry to open. They just need to remember to then close or delete the previous entry.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will definitely give it a go. I think the sticking point is that it doesn't allow them to easily preview changes to what is live - which is very much the point. If they have to start cloning things they may as well just do it on a dev site - which we have - and then manually copy over their changes. I'm going to (try) to contact EllisLab about this because it just seems such a fundamental requirement and something virtually all other CMS's can do without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Publisher](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher) is an alternative that is being [worked on for EE3](https://boldminded.com/news/ee3-add-on-compatibility-progress#continue). Similar to Better Workflow, not as slick IMO, but still does the job.

Comment: thanks for the information. The trouble is that it's being "worked on" and it says on the website "I'm hoping to release Publisher by March of 2016.". Well it's now June and hasn't been released. This is the trouble I'm finding with EE 2.x to EE 3.x migration in general - the developers of all these extensions are either not updating them at all, or are doing so very slowly. It's a real mess.